# "Attach to Process" as a post-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2008, automation, post-build

I have an application that runs hosted under the "w3wp.exe" process.

While debugging, I often find myself following these steps:

1 - Make some change

2 - Build the project

3 - Attach to "w3wp.exe" using the "attach to process" dialog under the Tools menu.

4 - Perform some action in the application to make my code execute, so I can step through it in the debugger

I'd like to automate step 3 in the post-build script, so that the IDE automatically attaches to the process after the build is completed.  Note that I already launch the application as a part of the post-build process, so I can count on the process existing at this point.

Does anyone know a way to automate the "attach to process" command?  Something from the command line would be especially nice, but a macro would do, too.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 under Windows 7, 64 bit.

**Edit**
@InSane basically gave me the right answer, but it does not work because I need to debug managed code, rather than native code.  It seems that vsjitdebugger defaults to Native code, and thus my breakpoint is not hit.  From inside the IDE, I can specify "managed code" and the debugger attaches as expected.  So is there any way to point vsjitdebugger to managed code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was finally able to solve this problem with an example I found elsewhere on the internet.  I'm sharing it here since this was helpful to me.

1 - Create a new command line application with the below code (this example is in VB.NET).

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
'On my machine, these EnvDTE* assemblies were here:
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading

Module modMain
    Function AttachToProcess(ByVal processName As String, _
                             ByVal Timeout As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim proc As EnvDTE.Process
        Dim attached As Boolean
        Dim DTE2 As EnvDTE80.DTE2

        Try
            DTE2 = _
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.9.0")

            For Each proc In DTE2.Debugger.LocalProcesses
                If (Right(proc.Name, Len(processName)).ToUpper = processName.ToUpper) Then
                    proc.Attach()
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timeout)
                    attached = True
                End If
            Next
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.Write("Unable to Attach to Debugger : " & Ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return attached
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        'to call w/ Command Line arguments follow this syntax
        'AttachProcess <<ProcessName>> <<TimeOut>>
        'AttachProcess app.exe 2000
        Dim AppName As String = "w3wp.exe"
        Dim TimeOut As Integer = 20000 '20 Seconds
        Try
            If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 Then
                AppName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)
            End If

            If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 2 Then
                If IsNumeric(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2)) Then
                    TimeOut = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2)
                End If
            End If
            Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
            AttachToProcess(AppName, TimeOut)
            Console.WriteLine("Attached!!")

        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.Write("Unable to Attach to Debugger : " & Ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

2 - Open the solution you want to debug in Visual Studio

3 - At the end of your "post-build" events, enter a call to this new utility, as in:

```
c:\AutoAttach.exe w3wp.exe 20000
```

4 - Build your application

Comment: we need to update the string "VisualStudio.DTE.9.0" for the respective visual studio version.

For VisualStudio2012, it will be "VisualStudio.DTE.11.0"

Comment: For Visual studio 2015 it will be "VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following command from the Windows command line.

If it works as you expect, you can put it as part of your postbuild steps.

ProcessID is the ID of the process you have launched that you want to attach to.

```
vsjitdebugger.exe -p ProcessId
```

Other options for using this from the command line include :-
[image]

Comment: Upvote for a great suggestion, but it doesn't quite work.  If I use that command, it asks me if I want to use the current debugger, or start up a new one.  I choose the current one, and it thinks pretty hard for a bit, but then any breakpoint I have set comes up with "The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded for this document."  If I manually choose the same process from within the IDE, then the breakpoint sets up correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JosephStyons - Am not sure if this will work but is it possible for you have to specify the debug symbol folder beforehand in VS --> Options --> Debugging --> Symbols --> Symbol File locations --> <your folder where the .pdb files are located>. That may help the debugger know where to look for the symbols...

Comment: same problem, I'm doing with a powershell script executed in post build event and it ask me to use the current debuger or a new one but then the hitpoint are no hitted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a PowerShell function inspired by @JosephStyons's answer. Works with any VS version without changes.

```powershell
function Debug-ProcessVS([int] $processId)
{
    $vsProcess = Get-Process devenv | Select-Object -First 1
    if (!$vsProcess) {throw "Visual Studio is not running"}
    $vsMajorVersion = $vsProcess.FileVersion -replace '^(\d+).*', '$1'
    $dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.$vsMajorVersion.0")
    $debugee = $dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses | ? {$_.ProcessID -eq $processId}
    if (!$debugee) {throw "Process with ID $processId does not exist."}
    $debugee.Attach()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is improved version of Joseph. I added this:
-dont show console (Set on your Project in "Application" the Output Type to "Windows Application".)
- i set timeout command line argument to 0 (why is it needed at all?)
- added third command line arg url, which is launched with firefox, but only after site is first loaded internally in program. this is because some sites, especially dotnetnuke, take long time to load after compile. so this way firefox will bring you into foreground firefox browser only after everything is ready to test, it takes up to 1 minute on my computer. you can work on something else in the mean time.
PS. this stackoverflow editor is a little dumb. thats why this text is not formatted pretty. if i add list bulletins code below doesnt show as code.

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit Off
Imports System
'On my machine, these EnvDTE* assemblies were here:
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\PublicAssemblies
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net

Module modMain
    Function AttachToProcess(ByVal processName As String, _
                             ByVal Timeout As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim proc As EnvDTE.Process
        Dim attached As Boolean
        Dim DTE2 As EnvDTE80.DTE2

        Try
            DTE2 = _
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0")

            For Each proc In DTE2.Debugger.LocalProcesses
                If (Right(proc.Name, Len(processName)).ToUpper = processName.ToUpper) Then
                    proc.Attach()
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Timeout)
                    attached = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.Write("Unable to Attach to Debugger : " & Ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return attached
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        'to call w/ Command Line arguments follow this syntax
        'AttachProcess <<ProcessName>> <<TimeOut>>
        'AttachProcess app.exe 2000
        Dim AppName As String = "w3wp.exe"
        Dim TimeOut As Integer = 20000 '20 Seconds
        Dim Url As String = "http://www.dnndev.me/"
        Try
            If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 1 Then
                AppName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)
            End If

            If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 2 Then
                If IsNumeric(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2)) Then
                    TimeOut = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(2)
                End If
            End If

            If Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Length > 3 Then
                Url = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(3)
            End If

            Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
            AttachToProcess(AppName, TimeOut)
            'Console.WriteLine("Attached!!")

            'load site for faster opening later
            Using client = New WebClient()
                Dim contents = client.DownloadString(Url)
            End Using

            'open site in firefox
            Dim ExternalProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
            ExternalProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-url " & Url
            ExternalProcess.Start()
            'ExternalProcess.WaitForExit()

        Catch Ex As Exception
            Console.Write("Unable to Attach to Debugger : " & Ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: This doesn't work form me. Using VS2015, could that be the reason? Basically use the build events to run a program, then this program to "attach". I added a BP to my main project but it is not hit. I can do it manually without issue.