# Compilation succeeded even though there were some errors from Roslyn Diagnostic Analyzer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, roslyn, vsix

The `DiagnosticAnalyzer` is a custom Roslyn based extension whose `DiagnosticDescriptor` with `DiagnosticSeverity.Error` is as shown below

```
internal static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Description, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
```

When the extension is used it does show the ***red squiggles over the codes*** that is against the Diagnostic Analyzers custom rule emphasising that **it is an error**, it is even shown in the Error List window of Visual Studio.

**But when compiled**, this code gets a **compilation succeeded** message in the Output Window of Visual Studio. This is working against the whole concept of emphasising an error as severity for a diagnostic analyzer.

[image: Error compiled successfully]

If this is the default way of working for Roslyn, then **do we have a work around for stopping the compilation**.

I'm using:

1. Visual Studio 2013 Update 3
2. Roslyn End User Preview.vsix
3. VSIX extension containing the DiagnosticAnalyzer made using Roslyn SDK Project Templates.vsix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integration of diagnostics into the actual build pipeline has been happening as part of VS "14". If you try the same scenario there, it will cause a compilation error.

Additionally, diagnostics are now attached to projects and distributed via NuGet so that the errors will happen consistently for the entire team, continuous integration build, etc.

Comment: So what do I do to get compilation errors for Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 (*because if I can't then there is no use in developing a DiagnosticAnalyzer for my project which is using VS2013-U3, should there be a work-around to stop the compilation please do mention it*), and I'm not clear about the NuGet distribution of Diagnostics.

Comment: There isn't a way built into Roslyn for VS 2013 - we've been focusing our efforts on VS "14".  You could think about making a custom build task that runs your diagnostics as part of MSBuild. If you want to pursue this route, the following answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052115/roslyn-workspace-loads-in-console-application-but-not-in-msbuild-task/15337218#15337218.

Comment: Distributing diagnostics via NuGet meant that they can be packaged with the libraries they target, and that the configured set of diagnostics travels with the project, instead of depending on which vsixes each user happens to have installed.

Comment: The example that you showed requires me to change the `csproj` of the project that I'm compiling. This cannot be done because of a lot of adoption issues as this will be used for internal code quality monitoring for our mainstream projects. Can we use the DTE [OnBuildBegin event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.buildeventsclass.onbuildbegin.aspx) to get the information from error list and then hard stop a build. How can we run a diagnostic when I start a build? How to make use of it to stop a build?

Comment: I don't know the answers to those questions.  Maybe you should ask a separate question for them?

Comment: Did you pursue this any further? I'm in VS2015 and an error from an analyzer isn't breaking the build.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using VS2015 Update 3 and this issue is still there. I wanted to enforce local variable and parameter naming conventions, it turned out Roslyn doesn't support these by default, only by workaround: [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004656/how-can-i-identify-and-analyze-local-variables-and-parameters-with-roslyn-code-d)

Then I wanted to fail the build if there is such an error, but Roslyn is not capable of this.

Roslyn could have been a very robust and powerful tool, but it is still failing in the most basic tasks. What a pity.

(For the moderators: I still don't have 50 rep to comment and I don't think I will ever have)

Comment: They say there is a workaround, it will work (break the build) if the analyzer is created as a NuGet package. [Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/8068)

Comment: I tried it and it is working if the Analyzer is uploaded to a NuGet store and the project references it as a NuGet package.