# How can I identify and analyze local variables and parameters with Roslyn code diagnostics?

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

I'm confused which method to use on the `AnalysisContext context` object to have every function/method's local variables anazlyed: either `RegisterSymbolAction()` or `RegisterSyntaxNodeAction()`.

It's likely `RegisterSymbolAction()` as per the sample Diagnostic with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX) in the [Roslyn SDK Project Templates.vsix](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/849f3ab1-05cf-4682-b4af-ef995e2aa1a5).

I'm debugging using a simple console app whose `Main()` has a handful of local variables of type `string` and `int`.

I've tried these two, but neither will trigger any variable to be analyzed in their respective `AnalyzeSymbol()` callback methods. Breakpoint within each of those callback methods don't get hit for the local variables.

How can I get local variables to be analyzed in the callback method `AnalyzeSymbol()` and/or what am I doing wrong?

```
var symbolsToActOn = new[] { SymbolKind.Local, SymbolKind.Parameter, SymbolKind.Field }; 
context.RegisterSymbolAction(AnalyzeSymbol, symbolsToActOn);
```

or

```
var syntaxTypes = new[] { SyntaxKind.IdentifierName, SyntaxKind.IdentifierToken, SyntaxKind.Parameter };
context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeSyntaxNode, syntaxTypes);
```

My [demo project is on GitHub](https://github.com/philoushka/dehungarian) for a closer look, and the specific piece is in [DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs](https://github.com/philoushka/dehungarian/blob/master/dehungarian/dehungarian/DiagnosticAnalyzer.cs).

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately `RegisterSymbolAction` currently only work methods and above.  For locals, and parameters you need to use `RegisterSyntaxNodeAction`. We hope to address this in a later build.

Comment: What is the status of this? We would like to be able to semantically analyze local symbols inside methods / code blocks?

Comment: nice to see a ref to docs where this fact is described